# What is the state of the Panno variation of the King's Indian Defense Saemisch?

Tags: opening, kings-indian, saemisch

In the Saemisch King's Indian

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "10"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. f3 O-O
```

It seems current (2017) literature and practice promotes Black's play 6...c5.  What I am wondering is there something wrong with the Panno (6...Nc6 with a6, Rb8, b5) that got players to move to 6...c5 or is it just the current trend?

Comment: Are you asking about the Saemisch or about the Panno variation? They are two different lines, in particular the latter arises from the fianchetto against the King's Indian, whereas the former doesn't.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco no there is a Panno variation against the Saemisch System and also against the fianchetto variation

Comment: @GennaroTedesco The idea Nc6, a6, Rb8, b5 can also be played against the Sämisch. See https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-are-the-latest-ideas-for-black-against-the-samisch-kings-indian-defense/9664#9664

Comment: I wonder, is this question a possible duplicate of https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-are-the-latest-ideas-for-black-against-the-samisch-kings-indian-defense?

Comment: @Maxwell86 Of course you can technically play Nc6, a6, Rb8, b5 against anything in the world, that doesn't award it the name of "Panno variation" though.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco I don't know much about names of openings, but it seems that the OP and Don are correct by calling it the Panno variation, see wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Indian_Defence,_S%C3%A4misch_Variation#Panno_Variation:_6...Nc6

Answer (score 1):

The Panno is a sharp line that has received a lot of attention lately, particularly the variation below where White opens the centre favourably. The variation isn't refuted by any means, but Black players have found this variation to be uncomfortable.

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "12"]

1. d4 Nf6
2. c4 g6
3. Nc3 Bg7
4. e4 d6
5. f3 O-O
6. Be3 Nc6
7. Nge2 a6
8. Qd2 Rb8
9. h4 h5
10. O-O-O b5
11. Bh6 Bh6
12. Qxh6 e5
13. dxe5
```